# For a two sample t-test, what is the relationship between the p-value and the test statistic?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, two-sample

Suppose we have a two sample t-test where the data have unequal variances and different counts. Let $X_1, \ldots, X_{N_1}$ be the first set of data and $Y_1, \ldots, Y_{N_2}$ be the second set of data. Then, a test statistic for this can be written from the Welch's Two-Sample Test as:

$$
T = \dfrac{\bar{X}- \bar{Y}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{s_1^2}{N_1} + \dfrac{s_2^2}{N_2}}}
$$

where $s_1^2$ and $s_2^2$ are the sample variances.

Then, by the definition of the p-value, it is the probability of our test statistic being as extreme as our observed data. Hence,

$$
p = \mathbb{P}\left(T>t|H_0 \ \text{true}\right)
$$

Now, my question is, is $t$ the computed test statistic under the formula:

$$
\dfrac{\bar{X}- \bar{Y}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{s_1^2}{N_1} + \dfrac{s_2^2}{N_2}}}
$$

using the real data? Do we then MUST know the distributional form of $T$?

Comment: please define p, P and T.

Comment: $p$ is the p-value, $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability operator. $T$ is a test statistic

Comment: An answer that touches on aspects of your question is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124961/reporting-degrees-of-freedom-for-welch-t-test/124966#124966)

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing "do we then MUST know". Do you mean "Do we then know" or something else?

Comment: p= P(T> t|H0 true)  Please explain the terms in simple way.

Comment: Do you want to understand the relationship ... or  you want an answer to your querry at the end ?