# The exact value of Welch's t test degrees of freedom

Tags: t-test, degrees-of-freedom

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test) defines an equation to approximate the degrees of freedom in Welch's t test and does not state anything about the exact value. Is there a reason why we could not evaluate the exact **df** and have to use the approximation? Also, it says that:

> The approximate degrees of freedom are rounded down to the nearest
>   integer [citation needed]

An explanation of why we should be rounding down would be also appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, all frequentist solutions to this problem are approximate.  You might instead use an exact Bayesian solution as in John Kruschke's BEST procedure which is implemented in R.

Comment: Some relevant discussion can be found here - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124961/reporting-degrees-of-freedom-for-welch-t-test/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** There is no exact degrees-of-freedom because the variance estimator in this test does not follow an exact chi-squared distribution.

---

**Longer answer:** The [Welch T-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test) gives an approximate solution to the [Fisher-Behrens problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behrens%E2%80%93Fisher_problem) (comparing the means of two samples with different variances).  It uses the studentised test statistic:

$$T = \frac{\bar{X}_1 - \bar{X}_2}{\sqrt{S_1^2/N_1 + S_2^2/N_2}}.$$

The denominator in this test statistic is the square-root of an estimator of the mean difference:

$$\hat{\mathbb{V}}(\bar{X}_1-\bar{X}_2) = \frac{S_1^2}{N_1} + \frac{S_2^2}{N_2} \sim \frac{\chi_{N_1-1}^2}{N_1} \cdot \sigma_1^2 + \frac{\chi_{N_2-1}^2}{N_2} \cdot \sigma_2^2.$$

This quantity is a weighted sum of independent chi-squared random variables.  Its exact distribution is quite complicated (and is best represented through its moment generating function), but it is **not** an exact chi-squared distribution.

The test uses the [Welch-Satterwaite approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%E2%80%93Satterthwaite_equation), which approximates the distribution of this quantity by a single scaled chi-squared distribution.  In this approximation the degrees-of-freedom formula arises as the best approximation of the chi-squared distribution to the true distribution of this quantity.  Without this approximation to the chi-squared distribution there is no single exact degrees-of-freedom.  Instead, the exact distribution is of a weighted sum of chi-squared random variables with the above weights and degrees-of-freedom.

Answer (score 2):

@Ben's answer is very clear about why an exact solution for the degrees of freedom isn't possible.

As for

> The approximate degrees of freedom are rounded down to the nearest integer [citation needed]

This seems unusual. There is a [section on the Talk page for the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Welch%27s_t-test#DF:_to_round_or_not?) that questions whether this is usual or not, and why one would round down rather than up.

[This CV question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124961/reporting-degrees-of-freedom-for-welch-t-test) discusses reporting non-integer degrees of freedom in much more detail, and gives a few sources saying it is "conventional" (mostly from the days when computations were done by hand and critical values of the $t$ distribution looked up in reference tables that gave values for integer df only).

Comment: I second this (+1).  With modern computing there is no reason to round the DF from the Welch-Satterwaite approximation.  It is best to use the approximating value without rounding.